# sram grip shifter to be fox CTD shock remote lever

Tags: shifter, shocks

the FOX shock CTD remote is a nice shock, but the remote is bulky, even the new 2014 version, still uneasy to change between CTD.

I come across this article
http://www.bikeradar.com/mtb/gear/article/trail-tech-clever-levers-37844/

the mechanics of Jerome manage to tweak by sram grip shifter to be the fox shock remote lever. 
it's such a very nice hack indeed. 
I wonder if anyone did it as well?

would one please post the step by step guide?

Comment: Looks really neat, but I'm guessing these might be one of a kind hacks.

Comment: all that guy did was mount the remote lever underneath his brake lever. he didn't turn the grip shift into the remote lever...

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the twister shifter instructions, but attach the cable to the CTD actuator (same as the current remote is currently attached, on the blue actuator on the shock), instead of the front derralieur. Adjust tension as necessary using the barrel on the gripshift.

Finding a SRAM front derraileur 3-position twister shifter might be hard these days (I think they only sell rear derraileur shifters now, since 1 chainring is the current "fashion") but if you find it... it's just a cable tensioner, same as the CTD remote.